# Setting up a Container View with a graph in Xcode throws unruly error

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, swift3

I'm getting the error below in my Xcode project. The goal is to setup up a Container View next to some settings and have this container show a graph based on those settings. Below is a screenshot of what my setup looks like.

[image]

The error was caused when I pushed the calculate button. I set it up so that the calculate button calculates some values of `exp(-x)`. However, I'm having trouble getting the data to actually show on the Container View.

**The View Controller code:**

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, CPTScatterPlotDataSource, CPTAxisDelegate {

    private var scatterGraph : CPTXYGraph? = nil
    var contentArray = [plotDataType]()
    @IBOutlet weak var hostingView: CPTGraphHostingView!

    typealias plotDataType = [CPTScatterPlotField : Double]
    private var dataForPlot = [plotDataType]()

    // MARK: Initialization
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.


        }
    }


    @IBAction func calculate(_ sender: Any) {

        // calculate exp(-x)

        for i in 0 ..< 60 {

            let x = -2.0 + Double(i) * 0.2
            let y = exp(-x)


            let dataPoint: plotDataType = [.X: x, .Y: y]
            contentArray.append(dataPoint)
        }

        makePlot(xLabel: "X", yLabel: "Y", xMin: -0.5, xMax: 1.5, yMin: -0.25, yMax: 1.25)
        contentArray.removeAll()

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var test_field_in_container_view: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var static_potential_user_input: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var starting_x_user_input: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var final_x_user_input: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var energy_density_user_input: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var data_from_file_radio: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var static_potential_radio: NSButton!

}
```

**The error:**

```
2017-03-15 17:50:13.327 HW5[78144:2576497] -[NSView setHostedGraph:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000120c80
2017-03-15 17:50:13.327 HW5[78144:2576497] -[NSView setHostedGraph:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000120c80
2017-03-15 17:50:13.329 HW5[78144:2576497] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8faa2452 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8b4e7f7e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8fb0c10d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8fa124d1 ___forwarding___ + 1009
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8fa12058 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   HW5                                 0x00000001000068b4 _TFC3HW514ViewController8makePlotfT6xLabelSS6yLabelSS4xMinSd4xMaxSd4yMinSd4yMaxSd_T_ + 564
    6   HW5                                 0x0000000100005b9d _TFC3HW514ViewController9calculatefP_T_ + 1117
    7   HW5                                 0x0000000100005f63 _TToFC3HW514ViewController9calculatefP_T_ + 67
    8   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff89e3207a _os_activity_initiate + 75
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f014dbd -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 460
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f026f12 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f026e3c __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 131
    12  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff89e3207a _os_activity_initiate + 75
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f026d99 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 144
    14  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff89e3207a _os_activity_initiate + 75
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0253be -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2693
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f06df04 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 744
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f023ae8 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 669
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f5783c9 -[NSWindow _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 6322
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f5793ad -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 212
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8efb8539 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 517
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ef38a38 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2540
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ed9fdf2 -[NSApplication run] + 796
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ed69368 NSApplicationMain + 1176
    24  HW5                                 0x000000010000d474 main + 84
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff858d45ad start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

Comment: Please filter down your code to what isn't working. Enough for us to duplicate this "unruly" error. Just enough. Not all your code. Thanks.

Comment: The large amount of code simply comes from the plotting section. If I remove this, people will ask for it back.

Comment: So we need to go through the IB screenshot  and 7 IBOutlets to know that the issue is with an unrecognized selector? Please read through this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Understood, but I don't even understand the problem, so how do I know what to show? My option was then to show as much as I think was useful, hence the View Controller code, the screenshot of the layout, and the error. It's a difference of experience, my friend.

Comment: Also, this wasn't "all of my code" either, I condensed the View Controller code. There is a lot more that I wasn't showing.

Comment: From the stack trace, it looks like there is a problem in the way your interface is wired up. My guess is that the `hostingView` outlet is not hooked up to a `CPTGraphHostingView`, but a regular `NSView` instead.